# How to replace faucet handle with no screws or cap

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I have an older faucet and I am trying to remove it to fix a drip. There is no logo on the faucet so I am not able to look up any instructions. The handle seems to be solid with no cap or screws. Any suggestions are welcome! [image: Faucet handle][image: Faucet view]

Comment: Looks to me as though the little knob on top might pull off or unscrew.

Comment: That or check the backside/side towards the wall carefully for screws/holes that have set screws in them.

Comment: Yep! It was the cap... it just looked solid to me at first. Thanks for the help!